# jQuery Click not working on stock Android Mobile Browser on anchor element

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

As the title suggests, I'm struggling to fire a click event on a link element.

I have the following HTML structure (I'm reporting just the interested part):

```
<!-- Table markup here.. -->
<td class="text-center">
  <a class="text-danger"><i class="fi-trash" aria-hidden="true" player-id="108"></i></a>
  <a class="text-muted"><i class="fi-x hide" aria-hidden="true" player-id="108"></i></a>
  <input value="" name="" type="hidden">           
</td>
<!-- More table markup here -->
```

Basically I'm trying to fire a click event on `i.fi-trash` and `i.fi-x`, in such a way that `i.fi-trash` is displayed when the page is loaded, and as I click on it, it's hidden and `i.fi-x` is shown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('i.fi-trash').click(function(){
    //Do stuff
    $(this).addClass('hide');
    $(this).parent('a').siblings('a').children('i.fi-x').removeClass('hide');
  });
  $('i.fi-x').click(function(){
    //Do other stuff
    $(this).addClass('hide');
    $(this).parent('a').siblings('a').children('i.fi-trash').removeClass('hide');    
  });
});
```

This works flawlessly in every browser except stock android browser.

I tried using vclick with jquery mobile, nothing.

I tried moving the click event on the a tag, nothing.

I tried using other events like `tap`, `bind`, but no one seems to work.

I tried switching from jQuery 2 to jQuery 1.9, nothing.

The only thing that works is moving the click event on the TD element, but then I would need to do some checking to see which of the two `i` elements I have to activate.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tested on multiple devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just after you ask for help, you find the solution...

To quickly reply to the various comments asking on which platform I tested my code: I know for sure that on stock AOSP **android 4.2.1** and **4.2.2** with stock browser the issue is present. Likely also on stock AOSP **android 4.4.4** and **CM based 4.4.4** roms (always with android browser).

It turns out stock android browser is not able to fire `click` events (and probably any other event) on `a` elements containing icons in the form of font (like Foundation icons), and on `span` and `i` elements (used for rendering these icons) unless you add to your css element `display: inline-block` .

I found out the solution when I noticed that the same exact HTML with Bootstrap css and icons (instead of Foundation css and icons like in my case) was not affected by the problem.

In fact, `.glyphicon` Bootstrap class has this rule defined (you can take a look at the core CSS file).

Unfortunately, since I'm using Zurb Foundation, I didn't have this line in my css ( `span` and `i` elements have minimal style with Foundation) and spent hours trying to fix this silly problem.

So, in my case, I modified the CSS in the following way:

```
i[class^="fi-"],
i[class*=" fi-"],
span[class^="fi-"],
span[class*=" fi-"]{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This should target every `span` or `i` element used for Foundation icons.

Answer (score 0):

what phone you're testing and what's the android version?

i had a miliar problem, where it would not work on Sony's default mobile browser(in a Xperia Z3 compact), but works fine on the ASUS Zenfone 2 default browser...

As far as i know, the manufacturer creates this mobile browser at will, so it can differs from phone to phone